# AS3: do anonymous objects get garbage collected?

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection

I do this a lot to configure new instances of classes

```
var myVar = new MyClass({param:1,param2:true,param3:"hello"});
```

Does this anonymous object gets garbage collected?

Would it be better to create and destroy the object after using it?

```
var myConfig:Object = {param:1,param2:true,param3:"hello"}
var myVar = new MyClass(myConfig);
myConfig = null;
```

Comment: That object will get passed by reference. And then the variable will fall out of scope. So they are effectively the same. So unless `MyClass` holds a ref to the object, it would be eligible for garbage collection either way.

Comment: If you are absolutely sure you will only ever need 1 instance of your class at a time it might be better for you to use a singleton design pattern. I personally use singletons for my config class so I never run into this issue.

Comment: I recently uploaded a sample singleton for Flex that shows you how to build out a singleton that acts like the Flex PopUpManager.You did not tag this as flex or flash. http://code.google.com/p/flexsingleton/

Comment: A singleton won't do it here. This is the way I configure new instances instead of passing a series of unnamed function parameters. Then in the new instance I usually have an object where I reference the configObject. What I want to know basically is if there is a problem when doing that. It seems that when I null the instance of the class, all references to the configObject should die and it should be garbage collected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are referring to "object literals", which should be garbage collected.

Flash uses two approaches to garbage collection - reference counting and mark and sweep.

If not caught by reference count, it should ultimately be released by mark and sweep.

**Reference Counting**

> Each object on the heap keeps track of the number of things pointing to it. Each time you create a reference to an object, the
>   object's reference count is incremented. When you delete a reference,
>   the object's reference count is decremented. If the object has a zero
>   reference count (nothing is pointing to it), it is added to the Zero
>   Count Table (ZCT). When the ZCT is full, the stack is scanned to find
>   any references from the stack to an object on the ZCT. Any object on
>   the ZCT without a stack reference is deleted.
>
> One of the problems of deferred reference counting is circular references. If ObjectA and ObjectB refer to each other but no other
>   objects in the system point to them, they will never have a zero
>   reference count and will therefore never be eligible for garbage
>   collection using reference counting. This is where mark and sweep
>   garbage collection helps.

**Mark/Sweep**

> Applications that run in Flash Player or AIR have multiple GCRoots.
>   You can think about a GCRoot as the trunk of a tree with the objects
>   of the application as the branches. The Stage is a GCRoot. Loaders are
>   GCRoots. Certain menus are GCRoots. Every object that is still in use
>   by the application is reachable from one of the GCRoots within the
>   application. GCRoots are never garbage collected.
>
> Every object in an application has a "mark bit." When the Mark phase
>   of garbage collection begins, all of those mark bits are cleared. The
>   MMgc keeps track of all GCRoots in the application. The garbage
>   collector starts from those roots, traces through each object and sets
>   the mark bit for every object it reaches. Any object that is no longer
>   reachable from any of the roots is no longer reachable from anywhere
>   in the application – its mark bit does not get set during the Mark
>   phase. Once the collector is done marking all of the objects it finds,
>   the Sweep phase begins. Any object that doesn't have a set mark bit is
>   destroyed and its memory reclaimed.

Comment: or perhaps even more simply put, you can't/don't "*delete*" objects by setting them to `null`; all that does it point that variable to *nothing*. You are trying to remove all the references to an object so that it becomes eligible for the garbage collector to think that nobody needs them anymore and they should be cleaned up. Even the `delete` keyword doesn't actually delete object in memory, it just removes a dynamic reference to an object on a non-sealed class.